# RxJs - Push data into an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I want to implement an infinite table in Angular, so when I scroll down into the existing table, I want to get the next set of data from the API. I am trying to do this with a `BehaviorSubject`, like this:

```
page: number = 0;
size: number = 10;
clientsData$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

onTableScroll(e): void {
    // get the next set of data
    this.getData();
}

getData(): void {
    this.clientsService.getAllClients().pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        this.clientsData$.next(data);
        console.log('this.clientsData$: ', this.clientsData$);    // it never reaches this line
      })
    );
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
}
```

But the problem is that, even if I used the `async` pipe in the template, it seems that it doesn't subscribe to the `BehaviorSubject`. So on init, this doesn't work at all, I don't even get the initial data).
I need to get a new set of data each time I call `getData()` and update the table.
I don't want to use `subscribe`, but to use the `async` pipe in the t emplate.
Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it never reaches this is because you haven't subscribed to it. An observable only "takes flight" when you subscribe to it.

```
destructionSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
getData(): void {
    this.clientsService.getAllClients().pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        this.clientsData$.next(data);
        console.log('this.clientsData$: ', this.clientsData$);    // it never reaches this line
      }),
      takeUntil(this.destructionSubject), // take until this destructionSubject emits
    ).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
...

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.destructionSubject.next(); // unsubscribe/destroy the subscription
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But why do I have to subscribe to it if I used the `async` pipe in the template? `this.clientsData$` is a Subject (which I suppose it should behave similar to an Observable also, since the Subjects are also Observables). If I do it like this: `clientsData$ = this.clientsService.getAllClients();` and use the `async` pipe, it will work. But in this case the problem is that I cannot push new data into the observable (clientsData$), that's why I tried to use a Subject (it has the `next` nothod to push data into it).

Comment: That's correct. If you don't subscribe, the observable never emits meaning the tap never runs. It is almost like dead weight. Personally, I don't think subscribing is bad, just have to remember to unsubscribe.

Comment: Ok, but my question is: why does it work to use only the `async` pipe with a normal Observable and it doesn't work with a `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: I think it will work with a BehaviorSubject as well but you're initializing the BehaviorSubject as an empty array and I suspect that's why you're not seeing it.

Comment: That's right, the BehaviorSubject contains an empty array, but on init I run `getData` which should populate it and I should see the data in the view, right?

Comment: The problem is that the `tap` on `getData` will never run unless if you `subscribe` to the stream, the stream being `this.clientService.getAllClients().pipe(.....`.

Answer (score 1):

You subscribe to `clientData$` via angular's aynsc pipe. This means that new values emitted by `clientData$` are automatically picked up. But you never send your `behaviorSubject` a new value (`next(value)`), so of course you won't see any data for it.

In your `getData()` function you create an observable (you don't run it) and then you return. So `getData()` doesn't do anything. You could re-write it as `getData():void{}` and this should all run roughly the same. It should be rather clear, then, that the call to `clientData$.next(data)` is never executed.

So how do you "fix" this? Well, creating an observable is like defining a function and calling a function is like subscribing to an observable --- you need to 'run' the observable you create in `getData()`. Subjects are both observables and observers, you can subscribe your subject to your observable in `getData()`

```
page: number = 0;
size: number = 10;
clientsData$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

onTableScroll(e): void {
    // get the next set of data
    this.getData();
}

getData(): void {
    this.clientsService.getAllClients().pipe(
      tap(data => 
        console.log('this.clientsData$: ', this.clientsData$)
      )
    ).subscribe(this.clientsData$);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
}
```

This should at least be running now. It hasn't accounted for error handling. I'm also assuming `clientsService.getAllClients()` returns an observable that will complete (or error) - it won't just stay running forever - otherwise you'd need a way to unsubscribe or risk a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can work but its much easier to implement observables in the following way:

- Think about what is an event (here onTableScroll)
- Write a function for your event and just next the `value` or `void/nothing` into a subject
- Use your subject in the observables and combine it with your datasource
- Only subscribe to the data that is needed in the UI or to communicate with some service (here clientData$)

```js
const { Subject, Observable, merge } = rxjs;
const { first, switchMapTo } = rxjs.operators;

const tableScroll$$ = new Subject();
const clientData$ = getClientData$(tableScroll$$)

function onTableScroll(e) {
  tableScroll$$.next()
}

function getClientData$(scroll$) {
  // Observable for the ngOnInit getData$() call
  const initialData$ = getData$().pipe(first())

  // Observable for the scroll$ getData$() calls
  const scrollData$ = scroll$.pipe(
    switchMapTo(getData$())
  )

  return merge(
    initialData$,
    scrollData$
  )
}

function getData$() {
  return new Observable(obs => obs.next('foo'))
}

clientData$.subscribe(v => console.log('clientData$: ', v))

onTableScroll()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```